# Fantasy series: auburn-haired boy whose mother/grandmother goes missing, flying airships

Tags: story-identification, books

I'm looking for what I believe was a trilogy I read back in high school.

I read this book/series approximately 8 years ago. It was a fantasy series with an auburn haired boy as the protagonist.

I feel like someone important to him goes missing. An older female. Perhaps his mother or grandmother? She's magical as I remember.

There's also flying airships throughout the series, and the cover of one of the books is I believe a red-ish colour with said airship. One of the enemy airships possessed a powerful cannon of some sort as I recall.

In the final book, I remember vaguely some voyage/trip to a strange land. I believe the boy finds the missing family member in the end, but she makes a great sacrifice.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This has elements of [*The Voyage of the Jerle Shannara*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/15553.The_Voyage_of_the_Jerle_Shannara_Trilogy) trilogy, by Terry Brooks.

The protagonists sister, Grianne, is missing and believed dead.  A voyage to many strange lands by airship takes up the core plot. Grianne is later discovered to have been raised by their enemy, and is known as the Ilse Witch.

> Ilse Witch
>   A half-drowned elf carries a map covered with cryptic symbols–and Walker Boh, the last of the Druids, has the skill to decipher them. But someone else understands the map’s significance: the ruthless Ilse Witch, who will stop at nothing to possess it–and the powerful magic it leads to.
>
> Antrax
>   While in search of the elusive magic, Walker Boh is lured into a trap–caught in a dark maze beneath a ruined city, stalked by a hungry, unseen enemy. It is Antrax: a spirit that feeds off enchantment and traps the souls of men. Now the fate of the Four Lands hangs in the balance.
>
> Morgawr
>   The intrepid heroes aboard the Jerle Shannara have reached their breaking point. A centuries-old sorcerer, the Morgawr, vows to find and control the fabled ancient books of magic–and he is an adversary of awesome might with a fleet of airships and a crew of walking dead men at his command.

Comment: Wow amazing! Those names echo so fresh in my mind now. Thank you so much! How curious... I was just looking into the vast Shannara series and hadn't realized the trilogy was in there! The author's name or the word Shannara must have triggered a memory. Thanks again! I can't wait to read it again:D